# Exception "Only GCMParameterSpec supported" during decryption

Tags: java, encryption

Im making an app in android studio using Java which is going to be like a password vault. So the user registers, logs in and can then add login details to various websites, the details get encrypted and the user has to re-enter their main account password to decrypt the details. The problem im having is that during the decrypting process when decrypting and showing the login details, I get an exception thrown from my decryption methods that I do not know how to solve. And im guessing it's what causes the username and password field to be null since they never pass through the decryption.

I'll provide all code for the classes relevant in that process.

In RegisterActivity the user registers their account, details are stored in sharedpreferences for future access.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText firstNameEditText, lastNameEditText, emailEditText, passwordEditText;
    private Button registerButton;
    private TextView backToLoginLinkText;

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createaccount_activity);

        // Initialize views
        firstNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
        lastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
        emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        backToLoginLinkText = findViewById(R.id.loginLinkText);

        // Set click listener for the "Register" button
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String firstName = firstNameEditText.getText().toString();
            String lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString();
            String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            if (firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Create a new User instance (This will integrate with the Room database)
            User newUser = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password);

            // Use ExecutorService to insert the user on a background thread
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    AppDatabase.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).userDao().insertUser(newUser);

                    // Log success
                    Log.d("Registration", "User registered successfully: " + newUser.getEmail());

                    // Store the password in SharedPreferences
                    storeUserPassword(RegisterActivity.this, password);
                    //storeUserPassword(RegisterActivity.this, password);

                    // Show a toast message on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> {
                        String message = "Registration successful for " + firstName + " " + lastName;
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });

                    // Navigate back to the login activity on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> onBackPressed());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log error
                    Log.e("Registration", "Error inserting user: " + e.getMessage());

                    // Show a toast message on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error during registration", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                }
            });
        });

        // Set click listener for the "Back to Login" link
        backToLoginLinkText.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Navigate back to the login activity
            onBackPressed();
        });
    }

    private void storeUserPassword(Context context, String password) {
        try {
            EncryptionHelper.generateKey(context); // Generate a key (if not already generated)

            // Encrypt the password using EncryptionHelper
            byte[] encryptedPassword = EncryptionHelper.encryptData(context, password.getBytes());

            // Store the encrypted password in SharedPreferences
            if (context != null) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sharedPreferences.edit()
                        .putString("encryptedPassword", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT))
                        .putString("userPassword", password)
                        .apply();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle encryption error
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Clean up the ExecutorService when the activity is destroyed
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

PasswordAddActivity lets the user create a login to a certain website and save it in their vault. The username and password inputted gets encrypted by the encryptData().

```
public class PasswordAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText websiteEditText, usernameEditText, passwordEditText;
    private Button saveButton, cancelButton;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.password_add_activity);
        int userId = getIntent().getIntExtra("userId", -1);

        websiteEditText = findViewById(R.id.websiteEditText);
        usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        cancelButton = findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String website = websiteEditText.getText().toString();
            String username = encryptData(usernameEditText.getText().toString()); // Encrypt the username
            String password = encryptData(passwordEditText.getText().toString()); // Encrypt the password

            if (website.isEmpty() || username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(PasswordAddActivity.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Create a new PasswordEntry instance
            PasswordEntry newPasswordEntry = new PasswordEntry(website, username, password, userId); // userId is the current user's ID

            // Use ExecutorService to insert the password entry on a background thread
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                AppDatabase.getInstance(PasswordAddActivity.this)
                        .passwordEntryDao()
                        .insertPasswordEntry(newPasswordEntry);

                // Show a toast message on the main thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(PasswordAddActivity.this, "Password entry saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    onBackPressed();
                });
            });
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            onBackPressed();
        });
    }

    private String encryptData(String data) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            if (!keyStore.containsAlias("password_key")) {
                KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
                keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("password_key", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                        .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
                        .build());
                keyGenerator.generateKey();
            }

            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("password_key", null);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Clean up the ExecutorService when the activity is destroyed
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The PasswordEntry class is where the password and username is passed in and should be decrypted.

```
@Entity(tableName = "password_entries",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "userId",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class PasswordEntry {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public int userId;
    public String website;
    public String username;
    public String encryptedPassword; // Use the encryptedPassword field

    // Use the encryptedPassword field in the constructor
    public PasswordEntry(String website, String username, String encryptedPassword, int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.website = website;
        this.username = username;
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword; // Set the encrypted password
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return decryptData(encryptedPassword); // Decrypt and return the password
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptData(password); // Encrypt and set the password
    }

    private String encryptData(String data) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);

            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
            KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("password_key",
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .setKeySize(256)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .build();
            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);

            SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String decryptData(String encryptedData) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);

            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("password_key", null);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(CryptoUtils.generateIV()));

            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);

            return new String(decryptedBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the PasswordEntryAdapter class which handles the decryption and is responsible for retrieving decrypted details and showing them in the alert dialog that shows up.

```
public class PasswordEntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PasswordEntryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PasswordEntry> passwordEntries;
    private Context context; // Add this field

    public PasswordEntryAdapter(Context context, List<PasswordEntry> passwordEntries) {
        this.context = context;
        this.passwordEntries = passwordEntries;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_password_entry, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PasswordEntry entry = passwordEntries.get(position);
        holder.websiteTextView.setText(entry.getWebsite());

        // Set click listener on the lock container
        holder.lockContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> showPasswordDetailsPopup(entry));
    }

    private void showPasswordDetailsPopup(PasswordEntry entry) {
        // Inflate the custom dialog layout for entering the password
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.password_dialog_decrypt_details, null);

        // Initialize dialog components
        EditText passwordEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        Button cancelButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        Button confirmButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);

        // Create and show the password entry dialog
        AlertDialog passwordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(dialogView)
                .create();

        // Set click listener for the confirm button
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String enteredPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            // Check if the entered password is correct
            if (verifyPassword(context, enteredPassword)) {
                passwordDialog.dismiss();
                // Decrypt and show the login details dialog
                showDecryptedPasswordDetailsDialog(entry);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Set click listener for the cancel button
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(v -> passwordDialog.dismiss());

        passwordDialog.show();
    }

    private boolean verifyPassword(Context context, String enteredPassword) {
        // Retrieve the user's encrypted password and related data from SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String encryptedPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("encryptedPassword", "");
        String encodedSecretKey = sharedPreferences.getString("secretKey", "");
        String encodedIV = sharedPreferences.getString("iv", "");  // Retrieve the stored IV

        try {
            // Decrypt the password using EncryptionHelper
            byte[] decryptedPasswordBytes = EncryptionHelper.decryptData(context, Base64.decode(encryptedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT));
            String decryptedPassword = new String(decryptedPasswordBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            return enteredPassword.equals(decryptedPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void showDecryptedPasswordDetailsDialog(PasswordEntry entry) {
        // Inflate your custom dialog layout for displaying decrypted username and password
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.password_dialog_details, null);

        // Initialize dialog components
        TextView usernameTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
        TextView passwordTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.passwordTextView);

        // Retrieve the user's password from SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("encryptedPassword", ""); // Change to "encryptedPassword"

        // Decrypt and set username and password
        String decryptedUsername = decryptData(entry.getUsername(), userPassword);
        String decryptedPassword = decryptData(entry.getPassword(), userPassword);
        usernameTextView.setText("Username: " + decryptedUsername);
        passwordTextView.setText("Password: " + decryptedPassword);

        // Create and show the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Password Details")
                .setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }


    private String decryptData(String encryptedData, String userPassword) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("password_key", null);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding"); // Use AES/GCM/NoPadding
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(CryptoUtils.generateIV()));

            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);

            return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return passwordEntries.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView websiteTextView;
        LinearLayout lockContainer; // Add this field

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            websiteTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.websiteTextView);
            lockContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lockContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the EncryptionHelper class that helps with the encryption and decryption process during the first registration so maybe it's not that relevant, but maybe ive used different encryption processes there which can interfere with the future decryption.

```
public class EncryptionHelper {

    private static final String KEY_ALIAS = "my_secure_key_alias";

    public static void generateKey(Context context) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build());

        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }

    public static byte[] encryptData(Context context, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(context));

        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();

        // Combine IV and encrypted data
        byte[] combined = new byte[iv.length + encryptedData.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, combined, 0, iv.length);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, combined, iv.length, encryptedData.length);

        return combined;
    }

    public static byte[] decryptData(Context context, byte[] combined) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        byte[] iv = new byte[12]; // IV length for AES GCM mode

        System.arraycopy(combined, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
        GCMParameterSpec ivSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(context), ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(combined, iv.length, combined.length - iv.length);
    }

    private static SecretKey getSecretKey(Context context) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        return (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    }
}
```

If you need additional information or code let me know and I'll provide it for you.

Comment: This is nowhere near a _minimal_ example of the problem as Stack policy calls for, but your `EncryptionHelper` correctly uses `GCMParameterSpec` with the IV saved from the encryption; your `PasswordEntryAdapter` uses **`IvParameterSpec` which is wrong and a newly generated IV which is also wrong** (for decrypt).

Comment: Ive posted an answer post so you can see the changes, because I get this exception, javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException, and my iv does not get initialized properly.